# I don't want to have the error when I drop a table although the table doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am using Oracle 12c and I am not interesting to have an error while droping my table 'CONTINENT' in case it doesn't exist.

I did this

```
set echo on
set serveroutput on
alter session set current_schema=WORK_ODI;
set verify off
set pause off
--
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE  

drop table  CONTINENT;

COMMIT;

EXIT;
```

but it coudn't skipe the error when the table doesn't exist, how can I fix this problem please

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need a commit after DDL in Oracle.

Comment: I don't understand you well you mean I have to delete commit, if yes I did it but the error still here

Comment: You get an error but it doesn't stop the script from continuing so what's your issue? the fact it outputs it at all?  http://pastebin.com/YaK1Bv2j   This looks like the solution you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851246/suppress-ora-00942-errors-in-ddl-create-scripts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bad idea to **DROP** and **CREATE** tables on the fly. Anyway, if you really want to do it, then you need to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to do this in **PL/SQL**.

For example, you could write an anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE table_name';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

On a side note, **DROP** is a **DDL** statement which will implicitly commit, so there's no need to explicitly mention **COMMIT**.

Comment: To reduce the script length (if you are dropping several tables) you could put it in a procedure,

Comment: "so need to to explicitly mention COMMIT" or rather there is no need

Comment: @Kamil Thanks, it was a typo.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem to skip the drop of a table if there is no table. But I think the problem with your script is one does not see in the log file if a table was dropped or if there was no table. Sometime it may useful you that you can extract this information from your log files.

Comment: @miracle173 And that is what OP's requirement is. Well, it does help in test/dev environments where you drop and recreate objects every now and then. Also, at times you would need to put the DROP before CREATE to make the script re-executable. Then, the first time you know that the table doesn't exist, hence you deliberately want it to be skipped.

Comment: No, that is not his requirement. The requirement is  not to execute a DROP statement if no table exists. That does not mean  not to see if a DROP statement is executed.

Comment: @miracle173 Not sure where you read that requirement. I can't see OP saying that anywhere. Anyway, you could always check whether a table exists or not in *_tables view.